# Define a new variable based on the reactive column

Tags: r, shiny, shiny-reactivity

I am trying to define a variable `time_var_use` which will be another column of the user-uploaded data to the Shiny app. For starters, this variable can be equal to the other variable from this data uploaded by the user. The problem is that this variable should be equal to the column specified by the user in `input$time_var`, thus its values can change based on which name of the column the user selects.

The code for the app is simple:

```
 # 1. UI Design

ui <- dashboardPage(

    dashboardHeader(title = "My app"),

    dashboardSidebar(

    sidebarMenu(

    menuItem("Upload Data", tabName = "data_upload", icon = icon("folder- 
    open"))

       )

    ),

     dashboardBody(

      tags$head(tags$style(HTML('.main-header .logo {

                          font-family: "Bliss Pro Light", Times, "Times New Roman", serif;

                          font-weight: bold;

                          font-size: 30px;

                          }

                          '))),

tabItems(

  tabItem(tabName = "data_upload",

          fluidRow(

            box(title = "Modelling data", status = "primary",

                fileInput(inputId = "main_data", label = "Upload the data for modelling", accept = c('.csv', 'text/comma-separated-values,text/plain', 'text/csv', 'csv')),

                checkboxInput(inputId = "header", label = "The data has headers", value = TRUE),

                radioButtons(inputId = "sep", label = "Delimiter:", choices = c("Comma" = ",","Semicolon" = ";","Tab" = "\t"), selected = ";")

            )
          ),
          fluidRow(

            box(title = "Divide modelling data into estimation & validation sample", status = "primary", width = 12,

                selectizeInput(inputId = "time_var", label = "Select the time variable", choices = "", multiple = FALSE),

                selectizeInput(inputId = "time_threshold", label = "Select time threshold for estimation and validation", choices = "", multiple = FALSE)

            )
          )
  )
)
)
)


 # 2. Server Design

server <- function(input, output, session) {

   model_data <- reactive({

     infile <- input$main_data



 if (is.null(infile))

  return(NULL)

read.csv(infile$datapath, header = input$header, sep = input$sep, 
 stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

 })

   # update time_var choices
  observe({

vchoices <- names(model_data())

updateSelectizeInput(session = session, inputId = "time_var", choices = 
   vchoices)

 })

model_data_use <- reactive({

if (is.null(input$time_var))

  return(NULL)

df <- model_data()

df$time_var_use <- df[, input$time_var]

df

 })

  observe({

tchoices <- names(model_data_use())

updateSelectizeInput(session = session, inputId = "time_threshold", choices 
  = tchoices)

    })




 }


# 3. Create ShinyApp

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

The problem seems to be with the expression `df$time_var_use <- df[, input$time_var]` when I try to define a new variable `time_var_use` equal to the column selected by the user in `input$time_var` which can be any column of the dataset. Can you please advise how to define new columns in such way?

I am using the example CSV dataset:

```
     time var1 var2      var3
  1  2015q1    8    1 0.6355182
  2  2015q1   12    0 0.5498784
  3  2015q1   23    1 0.9130934
  4  2015q1  152    1 0.8938210
  5  2015q2  563    1 0.2335470
  6  2015q3    8    0 0.5802677
  7  2015q4    2    0 0.8514926
  8  2016q1    1    1 0.4712101
  9  2016q1   14    0 0.9747804
  10 2016q1   13    1 0.8571699
  11 2016q1   14    1 0.8738486
  12 2016q2   53    0 0.8467971
  13 2016q3   75    0 0.3191140
  14 2016q4   15    0 0.9608926
```

Comment: The `input$time_var` isn't `NULL` when you get the error. It's `""`. You need to check that it's not empty. Use `if (is.null(input$time_var) || input$time_var=="") return(NULL)`

Comment: Thanks very much, that really helped! Why is it that such a small thing decides whether the app is running or not? Now I am not sure where to put the if conditions and where not, is it only with reactive() and not with observe() inside the server environment?